# how to make a constant value adaptive in xcode IB

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, autoresize

Take the following image for example, width of top red rect is fixed to 200, width of bottom red rect is constrainted to be half of the screen width. What I need is to resize the 200 according to the screen size. Here, a constant could be a fixed width / height, or a horizontal / vertical space.

[example image](http://paste.ubuntu.org.cn/i2269019)

I can do this programmatically, by @"H:[redView(%d)]", @"V:[redView(%d)]", I can calculate an adaptive width and height. Sometimes when the layout is complicated, it's too tedious to do the layout programmatically.

So my issue is how to do this in IB

Similar issues:

(1) @"H:|-5-[view]-5-|", I need the 5 to be adpative on different devices

(2) @"H:|[view(100)]|", I need the 100 to be adaptive

(3) @"H:|[v1]-0-[v2]-0-[v3]|", I need v1 : v2 : v3 = 3: 5 : 2

How to do the things in IB, any answer would be a great help， thank you guys

I have a solution now, I can drag the constraint which need to be adaptive from the IB to a IBOutlet in code, then assign it programmatically, in this way, most of the things could be done in IB. But it's still not smart, is there a smarted one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your red box, control drag from the red box to its containing view (this can easily be done in the Document Outline view). Choose the Equal Widths and Equal Heights constraints from the pop up.  Edit the multiplier to be a percentage (for example 0.6 for 60%).

In a similar way, you can use Equal Widths with a multiplier to solve your other 3 cases:

(1) Add a constraint to center your view horizontally in its containing view and then make view 97% of the width of its containing view.

(2) Use Equal Widths with a multiplier of 0.3.

(3) Use Equal Widths to make v1 0.6 of v2, v3 0.4 of v2. Pin v1 to leading edge of superview with offset 0. Pin v1 to v2 with offset 0. Pin v2 to v3 with offset 0. Pin v3 trailing edge to superview with offset 0.

Comment: Thank you very much. You solved my issues. Yout point is to avoid assigning constant values directly, by percentage or by aspect ratio, I got it.

Comment: Now, I'm using another method, in the root view of my program, I scale the constant variable of each constraint in [rootview constraints], then dfs [rootview subviews]. but it caused another layout issue which I haven't dealed with. Maybe relayouting all my views would be much better. Thanks again.

Comment: What about @"H:|-5-[v1]-5-[v2|-5-|" ? I need the 5 to be adaptive? Thanks

Comment: That's a tricky case.  What you can do there is to add views to take up the space. Let's call them `sp1`, `sp2`, and `sp3`.  Set their color to `clear`.  Set Equal Widths between `sp1` and `sp2`. Set Equal Widths between `sp1` and `sp3`.  Set width of `v1` to 0.475 of superview and same for `v2`. Make sure you pin all of the views together with offset 0 including the spacer views.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the screen width like below

```
CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
```

then set the frame. for Example

```
yourUIView.frame = CGRectMake(x coordinate, y coordinate, width, height);
```